# Reload same ViewController as if it was called with segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have a collection view in ViewControllerA that I use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` to segue to `ViewControllerB`. Once I'm in `ViewControllerB`, i have another collection view I would like to use in the same way as `ViewControllerA` to reload `ViewControllerB` with the new input. I imagine this question is extremely simple but I am new and have spent far too long trying to figure it out.

`ViewControllerA's` `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let hero: Hero!
    hero = heroes[indexPath.row]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("HeroDetailVC", sender: hero)
}
```

`ViewControllerA's` prepare for Segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "HeroDetailVC" {
        if let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as? HeroDetailVC {
            if let hero = sender as? Hero {
                detailsVC.hero = hero
                detailsVC.heroes = heroes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the issue lies in the fact that in my `viewDidLoad` of `ViewControllerB`, the object "hero" has no value for some reason. I require it to have a value to load a label.

```
viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nameLbl.text = hero.name
}
```

When I use the segue

```
if let hero = sender as? Hero {
    detailsVC.hero = hero
    detailsVC.heroes = heroes
}
```

seems to get the necessary information to `ViewControllerB` from `ViewControllerA` but I can't figure out why the view controller loses track of the value or suddenly has nil when I try segueing to itself or instantiating itself.

I get this error:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Im guessing the object hero is not being passed. Why doesn't Xcode use the last known value for hero instead of crashing?

I've even tried instantiate with the following

```
let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("heroDetailVC") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

But as you can see I don't know how to pass a value for hero and heroes with that.

I had a similar error when building the segue from `ViewControllerA` -> B but i was able to fix it by right clicking the `ViewControllerA` and setting up a manual triggered segue to `ViewControllerB`. Xcode WILL NOT allow me to drag and drop to connect `ViewControllerB` to itself. What do I do?

Comment: Check that your segue is connected with `viewcontroller` or with your `collectionViewCell` in your storyboard?

Comment: Why do you want a second instance of ViewControllerB instead of just updating the one you have?

Comment: @PhillipMills Well honestly I don't need a second instance of ViewControllerB, but I do need to update ALL of the information on the screen. There are 4x Collection views and a label that updates when a cell is pressed. Is there a way I can update the information without making a second instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question.

```
let doesntMatter = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("heroDetailVC") as! HeroDetailVC
    doesntMatter.hero = heroesInSynergy[indexPath.row]
    doesntMatter.heroes = heroes
    self.presentViewController(doesntMatter, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For some reason when I tried instantiate view before it didn't work. I guess the code I found was old or something.

I only have 1 following question. Is this going to lead to memory issues with all the views it creates when instantiating multiple times?